# Linux port 25 is not working, and postfix unable to establish external connections at port 465, internal connection works with issues

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server, centos7, dovecot

I guess these are two typical issues, at least first one is. I'm trying to configure postfix dovecot on CentOS 7.

## First, the port 25 is open, but it is not accepting any outer connections.

The internal connection at port 25 is working. I did:

```
[root@myhost ~]# telnet localhost smtp
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 xxxx.com ESMTP Postfix (CentOS)
helo xxxx
250 xxxx.com
mail from:<user2@xxxx.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to:<user1@xxxx.com>
250 2.1.5 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
from:user2@xxxx.com
to:user1@xxxx.com
subject:Testing email
test test
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as CBE5F6039
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Then I checked my Dovecot server at `/var/mail/vhosts/xxxx.com/user1`:

```
./new
./new/1693231789.M572537P2155.xxxx,S=495,W=510
```

So for typical SMTP (port 25), my configuration is totally correct. But the problem is, when I try to either send out or telnet it, it doesn't respond anything. The log document is empty. So I tried `tcpdump -i any port smtp` and it tells me that port 25 is not opening at all.

So I guess this is just some typical Linux error, something blocking the port 25 from listening. Please tell me if anyone knows what it is.

## Second, the port 465 is not working.

seems like postfix is either not listening to it because of some misconfiguration or been blocked from port 465 by something inside my Linux. (Or maybe SSL is incorrect)

#### I tried `tcpdump -i any port smtps` and did `telnet mail.xxxx.com smtps` on my own PC.

The server shows me that port 465 did received the packet. However, the postfix is not responding anything.

So I looked at the maillog at `/var/log/maillog`, and it shows that postfix didn't recognize and respond to my telnet connection at all. Here's the log:

```
Aug 28 13:42:37 xxxx postfix/postfix-script[1692]: starting the Postfix mail system
Aug 28 13:42:37 xxxx postfix/master[1694]: daemon started -- version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix
```

Just simply nothing. So I guess there are some settings or firewalls on linux that are blocking services from 'actually' listen to smtp port. Anyone knows this?

#### Then I tried to telnet from localhost at port 465, but seems like even inner connection at port 465 is not working either.

On my server, I did:

```
[root@myhost ~]# telnet localhost smtps
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
helo xxxx
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

It just closed after 'helo'. Then I went to `/var/log/maillog` again, and it shows as the following:

```
Aug 28 13:45:57 xxxx postfix/smtps/smtpd[1974]: connect from unknown[::1]
Aug 28 13:46:01 xxxx postfix/smtps/smtpd[1974]: SSL_accept error from unknown[::1]: -1
Aug 28 13:46:01 xxxx postfix/smtps/smtpd[1974]: warning: TLS library problem: 1974:error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_srvr.c:640:
Aug 28 13:46:01 xxxx postfix/smtps/smtpd[1974]: lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[::1]
Aug 28 13:46:01 xxxx postfix/smtps/smtpd[1974]: disconnect from unknown[::1]
```

#### Here are my configuration files.

sudo postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = localhost, localhost.$mydomain
mydomain = xxxx.com
myhostname = xxxx.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
recipient_delimiter = +
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (CentOS)
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

part of `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = xxxx.com
mydomain = xxxx.com

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx,com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous

inet_interfaces = all
#inet_interfaces = $myhostname
#inet_interfaces = $myhostname, localhost
inet_interfaces = localhost
# Enable IPv4, and IPv6 if supported
inet_protocols = all

mydestination = localhost, localhost.$mydomain

virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
recipient_delimiter = +
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

Part of `/etc/postfix/master.cf`

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       n       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       n       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  #-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
465     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  #-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

Comment: CentOS 7 is over 9 years old now and quite close to reaching EOL, certainly not recommended for new deployments and installations.

Comment: SMTPS is explicit TLS which you should test with a client that "speaks" TLS/SSL like `openssl s_client -connect localhost:465` rather than telnet. - You have multiple `inet_interfaces`  definitions  `inet_interfaces = all`  followed by 
`inet_interfaces = localhost`   Your `postconf -n` output shows that the final definition is what gets used and thus Postfix only listens on localhost and not on all interfaces.

Comment: as postfix read like nginx from top to down I believe that this leads to localhost, please show `lsof -i :25,465`

Comment: @HBruijn, thank you so much point this out. Seems like the SMTPS server worked after this. My email client saids that my email successfully sent out, but my gmail didn't receive it (I checked spam already).

Comment: Message from google:
The IP address sending this message does not have a 550-5.7.25 PTR record setup, or the corresponding forward DNS entry does not 550-5.7.25 point to the sending IP. As a policy, Gmail does not accept messages 550-5.7.25 from IPs with missing PTR records. Please visit 550-5.7.25  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#ip-practices for more 550 5.7.25 information. u21-20020a05620a0c5500b0076841c3ee40si4976570qki.598 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))

Comment: @djdomi, Thank you for reply. I did that, and it's kinda weird:
[root@myhost ~]# lsof -i :25,465 \n
master  2826 root   13u  IPv4  32637      0t0  TCP *:smtp (LISTEN) \n
master  2826 root   14u  IPv6  32638      0t0  TCP *:smtp (LISTEN) \n
master  2826 root   22u  IPv4  32649      0t0  TCP *:urd (LISTEN) \n
master  2826 root   23u  IPv6  32650      0t0  TCP *:urd (LISTEN) \n
[root@myhost ~]# ps \n
  PID TTY          TIME CMD \n
 2621 pts/0    00:00:00 bash \n
 2883 pts/0    00:00:00 ps \n

Comment: never answer as a commentary, always edit your question instead please moreover, you need to have a PTR that matches the Mailserver name, meaning mx.example.com must resolve to 1.2.3.4 and reverse must match it

Comment: @djdomi Sorry, I'm kinda new to Stack Exchange. And that works, thank you so much!

Comment: you're still welcome ;) but remind that only business related question in a business environment are on topic. for similar not business or home and enduser question should be asked on [su]. keep us updated and if you solved it on your own, please answer the question and apply the solution to it. remember that you need to accept your answer after 24h ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thank to the comments of @HBruijn above, I solved this problem. The problem is that I configured two `inet_interfaces`.

One thing valuable is that seems like in the current postfix configuration file, the `inet_interfaces = localhost` is a default value, and uncommented as a defualt. However, `inet_interfaces = all` is commented. Therefore, you need to comment the `inet_interfaces = localhost` when you uncomment the `inet_interfaces = all`.

The file is: `/etc/postfix/master.cf`.